# how to group the repeating occurance of regular expression matching a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a following string in java

```
59701=Application+Development"">app dev</a>| <a href=""/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValue001=Data+Analytics+(formerly+Business+Intelligence)"">Data Analytics (formerly Business Intelligence)</a>| <a href=""/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValueID012=Small+and+Midmarket+Cloud+Solutions"">Small and Midmarket Cloud Solutions</a></td></tr><tr class=""CstmFldRow noVpad CfProfessional"" style=""""><td valign=""top""><label class=""CstmFldLbl"">
```

to which i need to apply a regular expression so that i need to extract only the texts *app dev,Data Analytics (formerly Business Intelligence) and
Midmarket Cloud Solutions.*

I used the following regular expression

```
        String text_string= "59701=Application+Development"">app dev</a>| <a href=""/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValue001=Data+Analytics+(formerly+Business+Intelligence)"">Data Analytics (formerly Business Intelligence)</a>| <a href=""/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValueID012=Small+and+Midmarket+Cloud+Solutions"">Small and Midmarket Cloud Solutions</a></td></tr><tr class=""CstmFldRow noVpad CfProfessional"" style=""""><td valign=""top""><label class=""CstmFldLbl"">";

        Pattern pattern_sub51 = Pattern.compile("\"\">(.*?)</a>");
        Matcher matchersub51 = pattern_sub51.matcher(text_string);
                 if(matchersub51.find())
                 {
                     store_variable=matchersub51.group(1).trim();

                 }
```

now it extracts only app dev text.How ever , to find the other text values i need to use patterns and match for that again repeatedly. Is there a way to do this to find values recursively and get them stored in java variable ?

Comment: `while (matchersub51.find())`, not `if(matchersub51.find())`.

Comment: @saka: OP pattern works as is, just `if` should be replaced with `while` - https://ideone.com/uravDh. Maybe the problem is with adding the values to the result, I'd recommend a string list (https://ideone.com/BW8yAY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes as suggested by @wiktor Stribizew , the following code works. thanks

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String text_string= "59701=Application+Development\"\">app dev</a>| <a href=\"\"/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValue001=Data+Analytics+(formerly+Business+Intelligence)\"\">Data Analytics (formerly Business Intelligence)</a>| <a href=\"\"/search/search.asp?cdlCustomFieldValueID012=Small+and+Midmarket+Cloud+Solutions\"\">Small and Midmarket Cloud Solutions</a></td></tr><tr class=\"\"CstmFldRow noVpad CfProfessional\"\" style=\"\"\"\"><td valign=\"\"top\"\"><label class=\"\"CstmFldLbl\"\">";
        Pattern pattern_sub51 = Pattern.compile("\"\">(.*?)</a>");
        Matcher matchersub51 = pattern_sub51.matcher(text_string);
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        while(matchersub51.find())
        {
            res.add(matchersub51.group(1).trim());
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```